# What is the starting point in JBehave BDD

Tags: jbehave

I have gone though the JBehave official docs and have started making a sample project work. I am clear with the 
1. Step1 : Write a story
2. Step2 : Map steps to Java

I am stuck in "Configure Stories" step. There are many options like extending JUnitStories, JUnitStory, Embedder etc. 
Which one to use ? 
And how can I make a simple configure story class work.

.withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT, HTML, XML)) is deprecated, so what to use in that place ?
Basically if I directly take the code snippet provided, it gives compilation errors. 
Could someone help.

The reference link : http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JUnitStory: provides a one-to-one mapping with the textual story via the StoryPathResolver.
   JUnitStories: provides a many-to-one mapping with the textual story paths explicitly specified by overriding the storyPaths() method.For your case, extending JUnitStories shall be enough.
2. For the format, please use it as following: StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.CONSOLE);

Comment: doing: new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.CONSOLE); - withFormats is still deprecated in JBehave 3.6.9, do you have any further tips?

Answer (score 0):

you need import libs belows

import static org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.CONSOLE;

import static org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.HTML_TEMPLATE;

import static org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.TXT;

import static org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.XML_TEMPLATE;

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the source code and it seems that there are two methods of the same name, one (`deprecated`) declared as `withFormats(Format... formats)` and other as 
`withFormats(org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format... formats)`.

So, in order to use `non-depricated` version you should write it like this:

```
new StoryReporterBuilder()
    .withFormats( 
        org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.CONSOLE,
        org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.TXT,
        org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.HTML,
        org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.XML );
```